# Music Play List

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a lot of mp3 files and i stored path of these file in MySQL database(`Path example: \music\1.mp3 , \music\2.mp3 , \music\3.mp3`) in `music_tbl` table.

I can play this music one by one because i use `OnClick` java for `html tage <A>` to play mp3 file.

But I want to make a playlist(Auto play for next mp3) in javascript and php, please kindly give me some way to do, thank you very much.

Comment: Have php print the file list in a javascript array or use ajax to retrieve list, then use your player API to change to the current file, if you have "onPlayEnded" like event available from your player use it to load the next file in the list. From there adding buttons to goto next or previous should be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at jPlayer. It's very customizable and is easy to use/install.

http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-video/